# execute sql script embedded in my setup project

Tags: scripting, vbscript, batch-file, setup-project

I need to run a sql script while installing my program. I made a bat file which runs the script, and created a custom action on the commit of the setup project. The idea is the installer puts the file.sql(contained into my main project) in the installation path and then the custom action uses this file. How can this be possible?? Because doing this I get 
this error: "There is a problem with this win installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected.". Thanks.

Comment: The problem was the path. In the bat file I have to reference the script as \file.sql. But I'm still not sure if this is the best way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use SQLCMD to do this in your .bat file.  A good example exists on [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/using-sqlcmd-to-execute-sql-scripts/422). See figure B on how to configure your path. Another path example is shown in a brief [article](http://www.sqlcmd.org/) about a SQLCMD startup script; search for "startup script" on the page.